# Let $A \in M_{nxn} (\mathbb R)$ such that $A^8 + A^2 = I$ prove that $A$ is diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $A \in M_{nxn} (\mathbb R)$ such that $A^8 + A^2 = I$. prove that $A$ is diagonalizable.

What I did so far:

> We know that A is a root of the polynomial $f(x) = x^8 + x^2 -1$. Now we need to figure out what $m_A(x)$ (the minimal polynomial) is.

But right there is what I had trouble with.
Any direction will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(x)=x^8+x^2-1$. Then $f'(x)=8x^7+2x$. If we compute the greatest common divisor of $f$ and $f'$ (say using the Euclidean algorithm http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=gcd+x%5E8%2Bx%5E2-1%2C+8x%5E7%2B2x ), we'll find that they are relatively prime. This means $f$ has no repeated roots.

The minimal polynomial of $A$ must divide $f$ (which has no repeated roots). Therefore, the minimal polynomial of $A$ has no repeated roots (and thus factors into distinct linear factors over $\mathbb{C}$). Thus $A$ is diagonalizable (over $\mathbb{C}$).

Comment: A smart way to go. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Let $p(x) = x^8 + x^2 - 1$. Since $t^4 + t - 1 = 0$ has a negative real root $t = \alpha \in \Bbb{R}$, it follows that
$$(x^2 - \alpha) \mid p(x). $$
Since we can construct a $n \times n$ matrix $A$ whose minimal polynomial is $x^2 - \alpha$ (if $n \geq 2$), it follows that there is a matrix $A$ which satisfies $p(A) = O$ and is not diagonalizable in $\Bbb{R}$.

But $A$ is diagonalizable in $\Bbb{C}$. Let $m(x)$ be the minimal polynomial of $A$ so that $m(x) \mid p(x)$. We have to prove that $m(x)$ has no multiple zeros. This is satisfied if $p(x)$ and $p'(x)$ has no common zeros. But if they have a common zero, say $\alpha$, then

$$ \begin{cases} \alpha^8 + \alpha^2 = 1, \\ 8\alpha^7 + 2\alpha = 0, \end{cases} \quad \Longrightarrow \quad \begin{cases} 3\alpha^2 = 1, \\ 4\alpha^6 = -1, \end{cases} \quad \Longrightarrow \quad \begin{cases} |\alpha| = 3^{1/2}, \\ |\alpha| = 2^{1/3}, \end{cases} $$

which is absurd. Therefore $p(x)$ has no multiple zeros and the same is true for $m(x)$.

Comment: Excuse me. How did you deduce that $3\alpha^2=1$? I thought that, since $8\alpha^7+2\alpha^2=0$, $\alpha^8=-\alpha^2/4$, implying that $3\alpha^2=4$. Per chance I did something wrong?Thanks in advance for any clarifications.

Comment: While it is true that $p(x)$ has complex roots, we cannot conclude that $A$ must have complex eigenvalues. We are given that $p(A)=0$ (true), but can only conclude that the minimal polynomial DIVIDES $p(x)$. If $p(x)$ was the characteristic polynomial, we would be able to say that the minimal and characteristic must share all roots and thus $A$ is not diagonalizable over $\mathbb{R}$. But this is assuming more than we're given. At best, we can conclude that $A$ *might* not be diagonalizable over $\mathbb{R}$ but definitely is over $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @BillCook, But I also know that facts. That's why I mentioned the existence only.